# Connecting two GNS3 setups in two VMs in the same PC

Tags: virtual-machines, connections, gns3

How do i connect these two gns3 setups in different VMs? It's all in the same PC. My end goal would be to ping each VPC to each other. I am already able to ping VPCs in with different VLANs but only within the same VM.

A visual representation of my problem:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea would be to connect each router to a local interface via a cloud object in each vm then have a network connection between the two virtual machines. How you do this depends on guest and virtualisation platforms.

Comment: when i connect it via UDP tunnel the ping request has the destination host unreachable error. what configurations do i have to change to fix this

Comment: What platforms are you using and what have you setup? Host unreachable could be a bad gateway or route configuration but we need a lot more information before we can be of further assistance.

Comment: i basically have two virtual machines each having its own gns3 lab. the virtual machine has a bridged adapter configured since i will be connecting this to another PC through an ethernet cable. 

each lab has an emulated 3600 router with the 16ESW slot. with 4 VPCS included connected via switches. my problem is that i cannot get my VPCS ping out of the GNS3 but i can ping VM to VM.

Comment: How does one GNS3 lab know how to reach the other routing wise? Your diagram needs to include some i.p addresses so we can assist.